# My 'change password' function isn't working, and getting stuck in a loop instead

Tags: python, function, pickle

Here is my code:

```
import pickle

current_user = None


class User:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def set_password(self):
        self.password = input("Enter NEW password > ")

    def __get_password(self):
        return self.password

    def __get_username(self):
        return self.username

    def change_password(self):
        my_password = input("Enter your CURRENT password > ")
        if my_password == self.__get_password():
            self.set_password()
        else:
            print("Please try again")

    def display_details(self):
        print()
        print("Username and password")
        print("---------------------")
        print("username is: ", User.__get_username(self))
        print("password is: ", User.__get_password(self))
        print()

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'username: {self.username}'


try:
    users = pickle.load(open("users.pickle", "rb"))
except (OSError, IOError) as f:
    users = [User("MichaelPalin", "P4rr0t"), User("EricIdle", "M0nty"), User("TerryJones", "Pyth0n")]
    pickle.dump(foo, open("users.pickle", "wb"))


def find_user(name):
    for user in users:
        if user.username == name:
            return user


def add_user():
    user = input("Enter NEW user > ")
    password = input(f"Enter password for {user} > ")
    users.append(User(user, password))


def delete_user():
    delete_user = input("Enter the user you wish to remove > ")
    user = find_user(delete_user)
    if user:
        users.remove(user)
        print('done')
    else:
        print(f'user {delete_user} not found')


def display_users():
    for user in users:
        print(user)


def invalid_entry():  # Response for invalid entries to menu.
    print("Invalid entry, please try again")
    print()


def menu():  # Display menu, prompt for and accept keyboard choice
    print("Please select one of the following:")
    print()
    print("Enter a if you want to add a new user")
    print("Enter d if you want to delete a user")
    print("Enter f if you want to find a user")
    print("Enter c if you want to change your password")
    print("Enter u if you want to display a list of users")
    print("Enter q if you want to Quit")
    choice = input("")
    return choice


while True:
    menu_choice = menu()
    if menu_choice.lower() == "a":
        add_user()
    elif menu_choice.lower() == "d":
        delete_user()
    elif menu_choice.lower() == "f":
        current_user = find_user()
    elif menu_choice.lower() == "c":
        if current_user is None:
            print("No user selected!")
            continue
        else:
            current_user.change_password()
    elif menu_choice.lower() == 'u':
        display_users()
    elif menu_choice.lower() == "q":
        print("Goodbye")
        with open('users.pickle', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(users, f)
            quit()
    else:
        invalid_entry()
```

There's clearly something wrong as it's getting stuck in a loop:

> Enter your CURRENT password > password
>   Enter your CURRENT password > password
>   Enter your CURRENT password >

I can see PyCharm is coming up 'local variable my_password is not used' too.

I tried removing `my_password = input("Enter your CURRENT password > ")` from the `def change_password()` block, but that just results in a fatal error.

I also tried renaming the first `change_password` function to `update_password` and updating the second one accordingly, so that it went...

```
def change_password():
    update_password()
```

...but that didn't work either.

This is the logic that I want to use:

- IF the user selects 'c' in the menu THEN do the following...
- Prompt the user to enter their current password
- IF the entered input matches their current password THEN prompt them to enter a new password and update their password accordingly
- IF the entered input does not match their current password THEN prompt them to try again

Any help please? TIA

By the way, I'm puzzled that PyCharm is coming up 'unresolved reference 'foo''. That section seems to work OK, but any insights on why that is and if it's a problem or not would be appreciated.

Edit: I've updated the code in line with the suggestions, as much as I can, anyway.

Edit 2: PyCharm said that `self` in `if my_password == self.__get_password(self)` is an unexpected argument, so I removed it, and that didn't seem to do any harm.

Comment: What's up with those `__get` methods? That's not very idiomatic. Just access the attributes directly.

Comment: Try replacing `my_password == User.__get_password(self)` with `my_password == self.__get_password()`

Comment: And please _never **ever**, even for fun, store plaintext passwords_. The time to learn about password hashing is _**now**_.

Comment: @Chris - "What's up with those `__get` methods?" - I am just following what we were taught in our tutorial. See https://i.imgur.com/zSnBKT7.jpg I don't know what you mean by 'Just access the attribute directly', can you elucidate please? As for the passwords, with all due respect the time to learn about password hashing is absolutely not now. I am struggling quite enough as it is. One needs to learn to walk before one can learn to run. One thing at a time. I'm well aware of the risks of plain text passwords, but this is literally just for learning, nothing else.

Comment: @Harun Yilmaz - I tried the following at line 70:

    def change_password():
        my_password = input("Enter your CURRENT password > ")
        if my_password == self.__get_password(self):
            self.set_password()

...but I'm getting "NameError: name 'self' is not defined".

I can see self is underlined red in PyCharm and it's coming up 'unresolved reference 'self'.

Comment: @double-happiness, that's a bad tutorial for teaching Python. It's not very idiomatic: the `user` class should be called `User` and instead of the `get_` and `set_` methods you'd just use `some_user.username` and `some_user.password`, accessing the `username` and `password` properties directly. But if you're in a class or something you'd better do what it says. Maybe the point isn't to teach _Python_, but to illustrate a particular form of object-oriented programming more like what would be seen in Java, C#, or PHP.

Comment: @Chris - "the `user` class should be called `User`" - it is, isn't it? But yeah, I'm in a class. The whole module is taught on Python, but it's just called 'Introduction to programming', and the last few weeks have all been on OOP. This tutorial is supposed to be about 'inheritance and encapsulation'.

Answer (score 2):

The other change_password function in the outer scope also requests command line input. try to eliminate all the unneeded
`input("Enter your CURRENT password > ")`
except for one and use parameters in your function calls instead.

On top of that, the outer scope change_password() function is calling itself over and over, because its shadowing the inner one. Try renaming one of the two.

Comment: > the other change_password function in the outer scope also requests command line input. try to eliminate all the input("Enter your CURRENT password > ") except for one and use parameters in your function calls instead.

I tried doing that with...

`npw = input("Enter NEW password > ")

cpw = input("Enter your CURRENT password > ")`

...right at the start, but then it comes up

Enter NEW password > 

...straight away, instead of going into the menu.

Comment: I see that you removed the outer-scope `change_password` function, now you only need to replace your `set_password` function with my suggestion and call it with a parameter inside the `change_password` like shown above (and remove the `npw = ...)` that you tired). With that you should be good ( as far as the loop problem is concerned)

Comment: thanks, but what happened to the `input("Enter NEW password > ")` line though? Surely that is needed because that's where the user creates a new password (it is actually creating a new password for _a given user_, which is a bit odd, I know, but that's just what our exercise asks us to do).

Comment: Yes it is needed but you have 2 of them, you only need it once!
The user is prompted to enter a password when you call `change_password` and that input is then given to the setter function.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm totally confused now. How do I 'have 2 of them'? `change_password` says "Enter your CURRENT password > " then `set_password` says "Enter NEW password > " - they are both needed, because the current password entered has to be valid before the user can enter a _new_ password... But in your version of `set_password`, you've removed "Enter NEW password > ". I can't see how that can be right.

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry, I misread. I thought you asked for the same input twice.
It should be fine then.

Answer (score 2):

You're not stuck in a loop, you stuck in *recursion*

```
def change_password():
    my_password = input("Enter your CURRENT password > ")
    change_password()
```

notice that you just keep calling change password over and over... also you have double methods for some reason, use the ones in you `User` class.

when `'c'` is chosen you have no context, you don't know WHO is trying to change their password, so first you must ask who the user is, try the following changes:
before your `while true` loop put `current_user = None`
change the entry for `'f'` to be `current_user = find_user()`
and the entry for `'c'` to be

```
if current_user is None:
    print("No user selected!")
    continue
else:
    current_user.change_password()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried...

    `def change_password():  
        if current_user is None:  
            print("No user selected!")  
            continue  
        else:  
            current_user.change_password()`

...but it's coming up 'continue outside loop'.

Comment: you need to do all the changes i mentioned or it wont work, also your function `change_password` is not needed at all as it will never work as is, delete it. you only need the `change_password` method in your `User` class

Comment: ah, I see what you mean now. I wasn't clear that this `if current_user is None:` stuff is supposed to go under `elif menu_choice.lower() == "c":`. For `find user` I'm still getting `NameError: name 'name' is not defined`, but I think it's getting closer. I'm going to update the OP with what I've got now. TY